# Retrieve paths of deepest properties in an object

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, nested-object

I am trying to find a way to dynamically create an array that contains the paths of the deepest properties in a nested object. For example, if my object is the following:

```
{
    userName: [],
    email: [],
    name: {
        fullName: [],
        split: {
            first: [],
            last: []
        }
    },
    date: {
        input: {
            split: {
                month: [],
                year: []
            },
            full: []
        },
        select: {
            month: [],
            year: []
        }
    }
};
```

I would need an array to contain something like:

```
["userName", "email", "name.fullName", "name.split.first",...]
```

Are there any built-in or external libraries that do this automatically? I was trying to use Object.keys on the parent object but this only returns the direct children properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Array.prototype.flatMap` for this -

```js
const d =
  {userName:[],email:[],name:{fullName:[],split:{first:[],last:[]}},date:{input:{split:{month:[],year:[]},full:[]},select:{month:[],year:[]}}}

const main = (o = {}, path = []) =>
  Array.isArray(o) || Object(o) !== o
    ? [ path ]
    : Object
        .entries(o)
        .flatMap(([ k, v ]) => main(v, [...path, k ]))
        
console.log(main(d))
```

Output

```
[ [ "userName" ]
, [ "email" ]
, [ "name", "fullName" ]
, [ "name" ,"split", "first" ]
, [ "name", "split", "last" ]
, ...
]
```

---

If you want the paths to be `"a.b.c"` instead of `[ "a", "b", "c" ]`, use `.map` and `Array.prototype.join` -

```js
const d =
  {userName:[],email:[],name:{fullName:[],split:{first:[],last:[]}},date:{input:{split:{month:[],year:[]},full:[]},select:{month:[],year:[]}}}

const main = (o = {}, path = []) =>
  Array.isArray(o) || Object(o) !== o
    ? [ path ]
    : Object
        .entries(o)
        .flatMap(([ k, v ]) => main(v, [...path, k ]))
        
console.log(main(d).map(path => path.join(".")))
```

Output

```
[
  "userName",
  "email",
  "name.fullName",
  "name.split.first",
  "name.split.last",
  "date.input.split.month",
  "date.input.split.year",
  "date.input.full",
  "date.select.month",
  "date.select.year"
]
```

---

If you do not want to rely on `Array.prototype.flatMap` because it is not supported in your environment, you can use a combination of `Array.prototype.reduce` and `Array.prototype.concat` -

```js
const d =
  {userName:[],email:[],name:{fullName:[],split:{first:[],last:[]}},date:{input:{split:{month:[],year:[]},full:[]},select:{month:[],year:[]}}}

const main = (o = {}, path = []) =>
  Array.isArray(o) || Object(o) !== o
    ? [ path ]
    : Object
        .entries(o)
        .reduce // <-- manual flatMap
          ( (r, [ k, v ]) =>
              r.concat(main(v, [...path, k ]))
          , []
          )
        
console.log(main(d).map(path => path.join(".")))
```

---

Or you could polyfill `Array.prototype.flatMap` -

```
Array.prototype.flatMap = function (f, context)
{ return this.reduce
    ( (r, x, i, a) => r.concat(f.call(context, r, x, i, a))
    , []
    )
}
```

---

> Is there a way to access any of those properties' value? Eg. `"d.name.split.first"` using the returned array at position 3?

We can write a lookup function that accepts an object, `o`, and a dot-separated string, `s`, that returns a value, if possible, otherwise returns `undefined` if `s` is unreachable -

```js
const d =
  {userName:[],email:[],name:{fullName:[],split:{first:[],last:[]}},date:{input:{split:{month:[],year:[]},full:[]},select:{month:[],year:[]}}}
  
const lookup = (o = {}, s = "") =>
  s
    .split(".")
    .reduce
      ( (r, x) =>
          r == null ? undefined : r[x]
      , o
      )
 
console.log(lookup(d, "name.split"))
// { first: [], last: [] }

console.log(lookup(d, "name.split.first"))
// []

console.log(lookup(d, "name.split.zzz"))
// undefined

console.log(lookup(d, "zzz"))
// undefined
```

Comment: and support is limited https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap#Browser_compatibility

Comment: I wouldn't characterize support as "limited" just because it's not accessible to ~5%. Maybe it's not even being used in a browser? JS developers building JS for the web are familiar with (or will have to become familiar with) having to polyfill things. Should this discussion take place on every JS question?

Comment: Just noting it so user does not go and use it blindly.

Comment: @user633183 Thanks a lot. Using the dot notation solution above, is there a way to access any of those properties' value? Eg. `d.name.split.first` using the returned array at position 3?

Comment: @NoamSuissa, I think I understand what you're asking. I updated the answer. Lmk if that's what you're looking for ^^

Comment: im impressed this answer had only 1 upvote, is awesome. My only problem now is how to handle array of objects, any idea would be awesome, even saving the first element as the property value would be good

Comment: @llermaly I have some other answers that refine and advance the technique in this answer, each handle objects and arrays of any nesting level. See [example one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67403427/633183), and [two](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66432478/633183) and [three](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52822287/633183). If you have questions, I'm happy to assist.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do it. Easiest is just a recursion to test if you have an Object and loop over the keys keeping track of the path on each step.

```js
var myObj = {
    userName: [],
    email: [],
    name: {
        fullName: [],
        split: {
            first: [],
            last: []
        }
    },
    date: {
        input: {
            split: {
                month: [],
                year: []
            },
            full: []
        },
        select: {
            month: [],
            year: []
        }
    }
}

function setPath(a, b) {
  return a.length ? a + '.' + b : b
}

function getAllPaths(obj, paths, currentPath) {
  if (paths===undefined) paths = []
  if (currentPath===undefined) currentPath = ''
  Object.entries(obj).forEach( function (entry) {
    const updatedPath = setPath(currentPath, entry[0])
    if (entry[1] instanceof Object && !Array.isArray(entry[1])) { 
      getAllPaths(entry[1], paths, updatedPath)
    } else {
      paths.push(updatedPath)
    }
  })
  return paths
}


console.log(getAllPaths(myObj))
```

written with arrow functions and default values

```js
var myObj = {
    userName: [],
    email: [],
    name: {
        fullName: [],
        split: {
            first: [],
            last: []
        }
    },
    date: {
        input: {
            split: {
                month: [],
                year: []
            },
            full: []
        },
        select: {
            month: [],
            year: []
        }
    }
}

const setPath = (a, b) => a.length ? a + '.' + b : b

const getAllPaths = (obj, paths=[], currentPath='') => {
  Object.entries(obj).forEach( ([key, value]) => {
    const updatedPath = setPath(currentPath, key)
    if (value instanceof Object && !Array.isArray(value)) { 
      getAllPaths(value, paths, updatedPath)
    } else {
      paths.push(updatedPath)
    }
  })
  return paths
}


console.log(getAllPaths(myObj))
```

Answer (score 1):

come on. Arrays and Objects are basically the same thing. There is absolutely no need for undefined checks.

```
data = { ... };

function paths_list( value, result=[], path=[] )
{
    for ( keydx in value )
    {
        if ( value[keydx] instanceof Object )
        {
            path.push( keydx );
            result.push( path.join(".") );
            paths_list( value[keydx], result, path );
            path.pop();
        }
    }

    return result;
}

console.log( paths_list(data) );
```

Prints

> Array ["userName", "email", "name", "name.fullName", "name.split", "name.split.first", "name.split.last", "date", "date.input", "date.input.split", "date.input.split.month", "date.input.split.year", "date.input.full", "date.select", "date.select.month", "date.select.year"]

Comment: Brilliant solution  

Comment: @masoudmanson When it comes to recursion, I like to keep things simple, because otherwise my brain starts to melt ;-) But ty.

Comment: @Holli I don't quite see the reason for the "come on" but thank you very much for the solution

Comment: That wasn't directed at you, but my fellow answerers ;-)