# How can I dynamically replace certain keys in one object with keys from another object?

Tags: javascript, recursion, localization, react-i18next

I have two objects that represent translations for two different languages. They are exactly the same in structure but the values have been translated.

**English**

```
{
  about: {
    title: "About",
    subtitle: "Something",
    table: {
      columns: [...],
    }
  },
  products: {
    columns: [...]
  },
  games: {
    details: {
      title: "Game Details",
      columns: [...]
    }
  }
}
```

**French**

```
{
  about: {
    title: "À propos de",
    subtitle: "Quelque chose",
    table: {
      columns: [...],
    }
  },
  products: {
    columns: [...]
  },
  games: {
    details: {
      title: "Détails du jeu",
      columns: [...]
    }
  }
}
```

I want to retain the French object as is, but replace all instances of `columns` with the English version from the first object. How can I do that?

The objects I'm using are quite big and deeply nested, so I imagine I need some kind of recursive function. I'm not sure how I can keep track of which key I'm on to do the replacement though.

Comment: Slow down camel - what are you trying to do? (e.g. give the broader context). This looks like an exercise in localization of an application. Is your application using a framework? What's the framework? EDIT: I ask because there is usually existing tooling to support what you're trying to do, like stuff from formatjs.

Comment: I am using React and i18next. I am also using `translate-json-object` package to automatically translate my EN file. However, I want to retain the EN `columns` keys instead of translating them. There is no way to skip specific keys with that package, so I'm trying to replace them after the file has been translated.

Comment: curious, why do you want to retain them? Are they not supposed to be localized within the app - e.g. they should be the same for all languages?

Comment: JSON is always a string. Your question is about JavaScript objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**concrete example**

First we establish a well-defined example, filling in some values for `en` columns -

```js
let en = 
  {
    about: {
      title: "About",
      subtitle: "Something",
      table: {
        columns: ["en_about_1", "en_about_2"]   // <-
      }
    },
    products: {
      columns: ["en_products"]                  // <-
    },
    games: {
      details: {
        title: "Game Details",
        columns: ["en_games_1", "en_games_2"]   // <-
      }
    }
  }
```

And we do the same for `fr` -

```js
let fr =
  {
    about: {
      title: "À propos de",
      subtitle: "Quelque chose",
      table: {
        columns: ["fr_apropos_1", "fr_apropos_2"], // <-
      }
    },
    products: {
      columns: ["fr_produit"]                      // <-
    },
    games: {
      details: {
        title: "Détails du jeu",
        columns: ["fr_details_1", "fr_details_2"]  // <-
      }
    }
  }
```

**traverse**

Next we need a way to traverse all `paths` in a given object -

```js
function* paths (t)
{ switch(t?.constructor)
  { case Object:
      for (const [k,v] of Object.entries(t))
        for (const path of paths(v))
          yield [k, ...path]
      break
    default:
      yield []
  }
}

let fr =
  {about: {title: "À propos de",subtitle: "Quelque chose",table: {columns: ["fr_apropos_1", "fr_apropos_2"],}},products: {columns: ["fr_produit"]},games: {details: {title: "Détails du jeu",columns: ["fr_details_1", "fr_details_2"]}}}
  
for (const path of paths(fr))
  console.log(JSON.stringify(path))
```

```js
["about","title"]
["about","subtitle"]
["about","table","columns"]
["products","columns"]
["games","details","title"]
["games","details","columns"]
```

**read and write**

Next we'll need a way to read and write values from one object to another -

1. `getAt` which takes an object and a path, and returns a value
2. `setAt` which takes an object, a path, and a value, and sets a value

```js
function getAt (t, [k, ...path])
{ if (k == null)
    return t
  else
    return getAt(t?.[k], path)
}

function setAt (t, [k, ...path], v)
{ if (k == null)
    return v
  else
    return {...t, [k]: setAt(t?.[k] ?? {}, path, v) }
}
```

**copy at path**

For each `path` of `fr`, where the path ends in `"columns"`, update `fr` at `path` with the value from `en` at `path` -

```js
for (const path of paths(fr))              // for each path of fr
  if (path.slice(-1)[0] == "columns")      // where the path ends in "columns"
    fr = setAt(fr, path, getAt(en, path))  // update fr at path with value from en at path
    
console.log(JSON.stringify(fr))
```

Expand the snippet below and verify the results in your own browser -

```js
function* paths (t)
{ switch(t?.constructor)
  { case Object:
      for (const [k,v] of Object.entries(t))
        for (const path of paths(v))
          yield [k, ...path]
      break
    default:
      yield []
  }
}

function getAt (t, [k, ...path])
{ if (k == null)
    return t
  else
    return getAt(t?.[k], path)
}

function setAt (t, [k, ...path], v)
{ if (k == null)
    return v
  else
    return {...t, [k]: setAt(t?.[k] ?? {}, path, v) }
}


let en =
  {about: {title: "About",subtitle: "Something",table: {columns: ["en_about_1", "en_about_2"]}},products: {columns: ["en_products"]},games: {details: {title: "Game Details",columns: ["en_games_1", "en_games_2"]}}}

let fr =
  {about: {title: "À propos de",subtitle: "Quelque chose",table: {columns: ["fr_apropos_1", "fr_apropos_2"],}},products: {columns: ["fr_produit"]},games: {details: {title: "Détails du jeu",columns: ["fr_details_1", "fr_details_2"]}}}
  
for (const path of paths(fr))
  if (path.slice(-1)[0] == "columns")
    fr = setAt(fr, path, getAt(en, path))
    
console.log(JSON.stringify(fr, null, 2))
```

```js
{
  "about": {
    "title": "À propos de",
    "subtitle": "Quelque chose",
    "table": {
      "columns": [                      // <-
        "en_about_1",
        "en_about_2" 
      ]
    }
  },
  "products": {
    "columns": [                        // <-
      "en_products"
    ]
  },
  "games": {
    "details": {
      "title": "Détails du jeu",
      "columns": [                      // <-
        "en_games_1",
        "en_games_2"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

All `en` values are copied to `fr` for each `"columns"`.

Comment: Very nice.  See my answer for a variant that also deals with array nodes.

Comment: Conceptually, this is more along the lines of what I had in mind, but there's no way I would've been able to write that. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

This answer is structured similarly to the one from Thankyou.  But there are enough differences to make it worth adding.

We will build a function `substitute`.  It will take a predicate, which accepts on an array path in our object, such as `["about", "table"]` or `["games", "details", "columns", 1]` and returns `true` or `false`.  `substitute` returns a function.  That function takes source and target objects, copying the values from to target at every path accepted by the predicate function, returning a new object.

We use `substitute` to create the function to solve this problem by passing it a predicate which tests if the last node of the path is `columns`.  Here's an implementation:

```js
const allPaths = (obj) =>
  Object (obj) === obj
    ? Object.entries (obj) .flatMap (
        ([k, v], _, __, key = Array .isArray (obj) ? Number (k) : k) => 
          [[key], ...allPaths(v).map(p => [key, ...p])],
      )
    : []

const getPath = ([p, ...ps]) => (o) =>
  p == undefined ? o : getPath (ps) (o?.[p])

const setPath = ([p, ...ps]) => (v) => (o) =>
  p == undefined 
    ? v 
    : Object .assign (
        Array .isArray (o) || Number.isInteger(p) ? [] : {},
        {...o, [p]: setPath (ps) (v) ((o || {}) [p])}
      )

const substitute = (pred) => (source, target) =>
  allPaths (target) 
    .filter (pred) 
    .reduce ((a, p) => setPath (p) (getPath (p) (source)) (a), target)


const replaceColumns = 
  substitute (path => path .slice (-1) [0] == 'columns')

let english = {about: {title: "About", subtitle: "Something", table: {columns: ["en_about_1", "en_about_2"]}}, products: {columns: ["en_products"]}, games: {details: {title: "Game Details", columns: ["en_games_1", "en_games_2"]}}}
let french = {about: {title: "À propos de",  subtitle: "Quelque chose",  table: {columns: ["fr_apropos_1",  "fr_apropos_2"]}},  products: {columns: ["fr_produit"]},  games: {details: {title: "Détails du jeu",  columns: ["fr_details_1",  "fr_details_2"]}}}

console .log (replaceColumns (english, french))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

We start with `allPaths`, which recursively finds the paths in an object.  For Thankyou's enhanced version of the object `french`, we would get these paths:

```js
[
  ["about"],
  ["about", "title"],
  ["about", "subtitle"],
  ["about", "table"],
  ["about", "table", "columns"],
  ["about", "table", "columns", 0],
  ["about", "table", "columns", 1],
  ["products"],
  ["products", "columns"],
  ["products", "columns", 0],
  ["games"],
  ["games", "details"],
  ["games", "details", "title"],
  ["games", "details", "columns"],
  ["games", "details", "columns", 0],
  ["games", "details", "columns", 1]
]
```

The paths are arrays of either node names for object or numeric indices for arrays.

We write two function to get and set values in an object based on such paths.  These are straightforward recursions, with the only complexity coming in `setPath` to handle reconstructing arrays separately from other objects.

Our main function, `substitute` filters the paths in the target object according to the predicate and the folds those results into a new version by setting the value at each path to the value found along that path in the source.  In our case, the paths we would select are `["about", "table", "columns"]`, `["products", "columns"]`, and `["games", "details", "columns"]`.

And our `replaceColumns` simply passes to `substitute` the predicate that tests whether the last node in the path is `"columns"`.

We should note that the object returned structurally shares as much as it can with the original object.  If you want it entirely divorced, you will need to apply some structural cloning on top of this.

The biggest difference from the answer Thankyou gave is that the helper functions are all aware of arrays, and handle them in a way to traverse and reconstruct object that include arrays.  Although they are variants of ones I've used before, these specific versions are not well-tested.

Comment: `o?.[p]` feels weird at first but it's nice to do away with `o || {}`, eh? :D

Comment: @Thankyou: Yes, that's widely available.  Sometime I'll get it into my REPL and then probably stop using the old-school style.  (Sometimes when posting here I spend the time to fix that up and others I don't.)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to accomplish this by flattening both objects, looping through each key of the FR object and checking if the key contains "columns." If it does, I replace that key with the EN key. Once it's finished, I unflatten the new object back to it's original shape.

```
const enFlattened = flattenObject(enJSON);
const frFlattened = flattenObject(frJSON);

// loop through each key in flattened FR object
for (let k in frFlattened) {
  // if key includes "columns"
  if(k.includes('columns')) {
    // replace value with EN value
    frFlattened[k] = enFlattened[k];
  }
}

const translations = unflattenObject(frFlattened);
```

Flattening the objects made the comparison a lot more manageable. I found the `flattenObject()` and `unFlattenObject()` functions here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/59787588/2262604

```
function flattenObject(ob, prefix = false, result = null) {
  result = result || {};

  // Preserve empty objects and arrays, they are lost otherwise
  if (prefix && typeof ob === 'object' && ob !== null && Object.keys(ob).length === 0) {
    result[prefix] = Array.isArray(ob) ? [] : {};
    return result;
  }

  prefix = prefix ? prefix + '.' : '';

  for (const i in ob) {
    if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(ob, i)) {
      if (typeof ob[i] === 'object' && ob[i] !== null) {
        // Recursion on deeper objects
        flattenObject(ob[i], prefix + i, result);
      } else {
        result[prefix + i] = ob[i];
      }
    }
  }
  return result;
}

function unflattenObject(ob) {
  const result = {};
  for (const i in ob) {
    if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(ob, i)) {
      const keys = i.match(/^\.+[^.]*|[^.]*\.+$|(?:\.{2,}|[^.])+(?:\.+$)?/g); // Just a complicated regex to only match a single dot in the middle of the string
      keys.reduce((r, e, j) => {
        return (
          r[e] || (r[e] = isNaN(Number(keys[j + 1])) ? (keys.length - 1 === j ? ob[i] : {}) : [])
        );
      }, result);
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: this approach is made up of highly complex functions and fragile as it will break if strings contain certain characters. i posted an alternative in hopes that i can give you confidence that it's not that hard to write these things on your own. please let me know if you have any questions