# How to traverse a General Tree (not BST) recursively in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion, data-structures, tree

Let's say that we want to model de hierarchical structure present in a company. The most basic data structure is called `employee`. Each `employee` is an Object / Tree of it's own and has two attributes: `level` which is an integer and `reports` that is an Object / Tree holding 0 or more `employees`.

We could say that the `employee` data structure looks as follows:

```
{
    employee: {
        level: Number,
        reports: Object //Contains 0 to N employees
    }
}
```

A small business could represent it's organization as follows:

```
{
boss: {
  level: 0,
  reports: {
    employee0: {
      level: 1,
      reports: {
        anotherEmployee0: {
          level: 2,
          reports: { /* ... */ },
        },
        anotherEmployee0: {
          level: 2,
          reports: { /* ... */ },
        },
      },
    },
    employee1: {
      level: 1,
      reports: { /* ... */ },
    },
  },
},
};
```

How can we traverse this structure using recursion? Ideally, doing it without language function abstractions such as `for ... in`, `foreach`, `map`. So, 'by hand'. I'd love to see both solutions (with and without said abstractions), to compare.

Comment: *"language function abstractions"*: I have never heard that phrase. What is that?  What is your problem with `for...in` -- it belongs to the core of the language since its beginning. *"by hand"*: do you happen to mean that it should be in ES3 and not a later version?

Comment: please add **your** try.

Comment: @trincot if you're using ES6 built-in functions you're using abstracted logic instead of your implementation aren't you? `foreach` encapsulates logic that you didn't write, isn't it abstracted? Can we call them abstractions? Sorry if that's not an actual term but that's what I meant.

Comment: @NinaScholz yup working on it. I'm just stuck, been practicing a lot with Binary Trees but noticed my organization cannot be represented as a binary tree. :P

Comment: @trincot Oh sorry forgot to answer the rest. I don't have a problem with `for ... in` or the rest of course they are useful but I want to learn how to manipulate the data structures at a lower level and those solve problems that you would otherwise need to handle yourself. They provide abstraction and I want to manipulate them on my own.

Comment: `{..., reports: { employe0: x, employee1: y, employee2: z }}` is a code smell and misuse of objects. This is precisely what arrays are for, `{..., reports: [x,y,z]}`

Comment: I have no idea what could be lower level than `for ... in`. How else are you going to inspect an object?

Comment: `10110` so when you "traverse" the tree, what would you like available at each leaf? Do you just want the leaf value? Do you want the entire path to each leaf? [This Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66432478/633183) I wrote yesterday includes a `path` function that might put you well on your way... Please provide an exact input and exact output you are expecting.

Comment: @trincot, can you write a recursive function instead of using a for loop?

Comment: @Thankyou About the code smell, I wrote it myself. Feel free to make adjustments to the structure I guess. As input you can provide the root node, which would be the "boss" key? As output you can just print `level` and maybe `name` (add the attribute cause I missed it)?

Comment: @10110, we can write a recursive function, but how do you imagine the code can know which is the property name in the given object ("boss", "employee1", ..) *without* doing a `for..in` loop? Can you please tell me? Maybe I miss something.

Comment: At the end of the day what I'm trying here is to learn how we can loop, iterate or traverse a structure similar to this one. Hopefully using recursion and avoid using functions or constructs that "help too much". Again I would use them in the real world but I'm trying to learn how to manipulate data structures. I know I can use `for ... in` and it's variants to loop easily through it but I'm looking for a recursive solution.

Comment: @trincot I see what you mean. Sorry for using fancy words where they don't belong haha. Also, I wrote that object myself trying to model an organization with a normal tree. I can see that there are better ways to represent the organization in JS. I haven't found many examples of general trees and how to loop through them so that's why I'm asking here. I do appreciate your help and comments. I'm actually learning and that's what I'm looking for. For some reason I thought the best way to represent an tree was using objects only. But I see now we can use arrays as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for..in` is a core language construct that has been part of the JavaScript language from its inception. It is the first way that was provided to inspect the properties of an object.

I provide here two solutions. The first one will stick to your data structure, and will employ `for..in` to read the properties of the given objects and perform conditional recursion on the `reports` value. It calls a user-provided callback function, so the user can decide what to do with the iterated values.

The second one switches to a better data structure, as it is better practice to not use object property names to represent dynamic content. Instead add a property to your objects (maybe "name") to which you assign that dynamic content ("employee1", "boss", ...etc). Instead of the old-fashioned callback system, it defines the function as a generator.

### Solution 1 (`for..in` + callback):

This is ES3 compatible.

```js
function traverse(org, callback, parent) {
    for (var name in org) {
        var obj = org[name];
        callback(name, obj.level, parent);
        if (obj.reports) {
            traverse(obj.reports, callback, name);
        }
    }
}

// demo with original data structure
var org = {boss: {level: 0,reports: {employee0: {level: 1,reports: {anotherEmployee0: {level: 2,reports: { /* ... */ },},anotherEmployee1: {level: 2,reports: { /* ... */ },},},},employee1: {level: 1,reports: { /* ... */ },},},},};

traverse(org, visit, null);

// Our function that processes the iterated values:
function visit(name, level, parent) {
    console.log("         ".slice(0, level) + name + " (level " + level + ") under " + (parent || "no one"));
}
```

### Solution 2: (better data structure + generator)

This also uses destructuring, `for..of` loop, template literal, `repeat`, `let`, default argument value, ...

```js
function * iterate(org, parent=null) {
    for (let {name, level, reports} of org) {
        yield [name, level, parent];
        if (reports) {
            yield * iterate(reports, name);
        }
    }
}

let org2 = [{ 
    name: "boss", 
    level: 0, 
    reports: [{ 
        name: "employee0", 
        level: 1, 
        reports: [{ 
            name: "anotherEmployee0", 
            level: 2, 
            reports: [/* ... */]
        }, { 
            name: "anotherEmployee1", 
            level: 2, 
            reports: [/* ... */]
        }]
    }, {
        name: "employee1",
        level: 1,
        reports: [/* ... */]
    }]
}];

for (let [name, level, parent] of iterate(org2)) {
    console.log(`${" ".repeat(level)}${name} (level ${level}) under ${parent || "no one"}`);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your solutions and for walking me through them. As I mentioned above, I apologize if the question was not clear or flawed. I also appreciate your comments on the data structure itself, the problems it has and for providing a better alternative. For some reason I was expecting to be able to iterate, loop through the entire structure using recursion and no `for` loops. It's clear I have a lot to learn! Sorry for posting the frustrating and confusing question! haha But I'm glad you still provided a solution.

Comment: I hope you understand communication on this platform can sometimes be dry and direct. Don't take it personally. We all share a common love for coding. Keep up the good work.

Answer (score 0):

Trincot's excellent answer used generators "instead of the old-fashioned callback system".

Here's a demonstration of how that old-fashioned system might work, using trincot's restructuring of the input data:

```js
const traverseOrg = (fn) => (org, boss = null) =>
  org .forEach (emp => {
    fn (emp, boss)
    traverseOrg (fn) (emp.reports || [], emp) 
  })

let org2 = [{name: "boss", level: 0, reports: [{name: "employee0", level: 1, reports: [{name: "anotherEmployee0", level: 2, reports: [/* ... */]}, {name: "anotherEmployee1", level: 2, reports: [/* ... */]}]}, {name: "employee1", level: 1, reports: [/* ... */]}]}];

traverseOrg (
  ({level, name}, boss) => console .log (
    `${'    ' .repeat (level)}${name} (level ${level}) reports to ${boss ? boss.name : "no one"}`
  )
) (org2)
```

Our `traverseOrg` function takes a callback function and generates a function that takes an array of employees with their nested reports, and calls the callback on each one in a depth-first traversal, passing the employee and the parent employee, or null if it doesn't exist.

We can use this for the same sort of output that trincot demonstrated, by simply logging the employee name, level, and boss' name.

Note that we  use `forEach` here.  We could many types of looping construct, but since we're treating this as a simple traversal, and not a transformation, the array functions such as `.map` or `.reduce` are not appropriate here.

We could layer out a flattening function on top of this, with something like this:

```js
const flattenOrg = (org) => {
  const res = []
  traverseOrg (({name, reports = []}) => res .push (
    {name, directReports: reports .map (({name}) => name)}
  )) (org)
  return res
}

flattenOrg (org2)
```

which would return this structure:

```js
[
  {name: "boss", directReports: ["employee0", "employee1"]},
  {name: "employee0", directReports: ["anotherEmployee0", "anotherEmployee1"]},
  {name: "anotherEmployee0", directReports: []},
  {name: "anotherEmployee1", directReports: []},
  {name: "employee1", directReports: []}
]
```

But there's not much reason for that.  It's ugly code, and we would do better to write it directly:

```js
const flattenOrg = (org) =>
  org .flatMap (({name, reports = []}) => 
    [{name, directReports: reports .map (({name}) => name)}, ... flattenOrg (reports)]
  )
```