# Creating deep filter by input value

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion, filter

I have an array of objects

```
[
  {
    id: "95c3-1e74-48c7-ec7e",
    name: "model.yaml",
    type: "file",
    path: "model/model.yaml",
  },
  {
    id: "115c-d112-5ce5-a7e8",
    name: "storage-complextypes.yaml",
    type: "file",
    path: "model/storage-complextypes.yaml",
  },
  {
    id: "9f51-93b5-4160-0237",
    name: "storage-simpletypes.yaml",
    type: "file",
    path: "model/storage-simpletypes.yaml",
  },
  {
    id: "05a0-d4fb-d461-9697",
    name: "newfolder",
    type: "directory",
    path: "model/newfolder",
    children: [
      {
        id: "e8e5-f0c8-6664-96e1",
        name: "newname",
        type: "file",
        path: "model/newfolder/newname",
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

The purpose is to get an array if only some of the objects name characters are matching , so it's checking similarity on each input occurence. Below, is what I want to see as a result if "newn" is typed.

```
[
      {
        id: "e8e5-f0c8-6664-96e1",
        name: "newname",
        type: "file",
        path: "model/newfolder/newname",
      },
    ]
```

Thats what I have for now.

```
const findItem = function(array, name) {
  return array.flatMap((item) => item.children).some((data) => data.name.includes(name)) || null;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do it in two steps: flatten and then find:

```js
data = [
    {name: "model.yaml",},
    {name: "storage-simpletypes.yaml",},
    {name: "newfolder",
        children: [
            {
                name: "newname",
                children: [
                    {name: "newname2", path: 'hi there'},
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
];

let flatten = d => (d || []).flatMap(e => [e, ...flatten(e.children)])

console.log(...flatten(data).filter(e => e.name.startsWith('newn')))
```

*For future googlers: be sure to also read other answers in this thread*

Comment: Or filter() to get requested array of matches

Answer (score 4):

**generic**

I will suggest a generic approach, `find`, that works on any input and any level of nesting. It accepts a target of any type, `t`, and a querying function, `query` -

```js
function* find (t, query)
{ if (query(t)) yield {path: [], value: t}
  switch (t?.constructor)
  { case Array:
    case Object:
      for (const [k, v] of Object.entries(t))
        for (const {path, value} of find(v, query))
          yield {path: [k, ...path], value}
  }
}
```

`find` is a higher-order function that works similarly to `Array.prototype.find` -

```js
Array.from(find(data, t => /newn/.test(t)))
```

`find` yields `{path, value}` results -

| path | value |
| --- | --- |
| ["3", "children", "0", "name"] | "newname" |
| ["3", "children", "0", "path"] | "model/newfolder/newname" |

Where the `path` can be used to lookup the `value` -

```js
data["3"]["children"]["0"]["name"]  // => "newname"
data["3"]["children"]["0"]["path"]  // => "model/newfolder/newname"
```

**specialize**

`find` is a higher-order function, enabling the caller (you!) to modify its output by modifying the querying function. Below we write a `matchProperty` to accept a regular expression, `re`, and an input `o`. If `o` is an Object and one of its properties matches the expression, we return true to signal that `find` should include this result -

```js
const matchProperty = re => o =>
  o?.constructor === Object
    && Object.keys(o).some(k => re.test(o[k]))
    
Array.from(find(data, matchProperty(/newn/)))
```

| path | value |
| --- | --- |
| ["3", "children", "0"] | {id:"e8e5-f0c8-6664-96e1",name:"newname",type:"file", path":"model/newfolder/newname"} |

You can be as specific or creative with these queries as you'd like. Instead of matching *any* property, we could write a more focused match -

```js
const hasFileType = type => o =>
  o?.name?.endsWith(`.${type}`)

Array.from(find(data, hasFileType("yaml")))
```

| path | value |
| --- | --- |
| ["0"] | {"id":"95c3-1e74-48c7-ec7e","name":"model.yaml","type":"file","path":"model/model.yaml"} |
| ["1"] | {"id":"115c-d112-5ce5-a7e8","name":"storage-complextypes.yaml","type":"file","path":"model/storage-complextypes.yaml"} |
| ["2"] | {"id":"9f51-93b5-4160-0237","name":"storage-simpletypes.yaml","type":"file","path":"model/storage-simpletypes.yaml"} |

Or maybe instead of finding all results, you only wish to find the first result -

```js
function find1 (t, f)
{ for (const r of find(t, f))
    return r
}

find1(data, hasFileType("yaml"))
```

| path | value |
| --- | --- |
| ["0"] | {"id":"95c3-1e74-48c7-ec7e","name":"model.yaml","type":"file","path":"model/model.yaml"} |

**demo**

Run the program below to verify the results in your own browser -

```js
function* find (t, query)
{ if (query(t)) yield {path: [], value: t}
  switch (t?.constructor)
  { case Array:
    case Object:
      for (const [k, v] of Object.entries(t))
        for (const {path, value} of find(v, query))
          yield {path: [k, ...path], value}
  }
}

const matchProperty = re => o =>
  o?.constructor === Object
    && Object.keys(o).some(k => re.test(o[k]))

const hasFileType = type => o =>
  o?.name?.endsWith("." + type)

const data =
  [{id: "95c3-1e74-48c7-ec7e",name: "model.yaml",type: "file",path: "model/model.yaml"},{id: "115c-d112-5ce5-a7e8",name: "storage-complextypes.yaml",type: "file",path: "model/storage-complextypes.yaml"},{id: "9f51-93b5-4160-0237",name: "storage-simpletypes.yaml",type: "file",path: "model/storage-simpletypes.yaml"},{id: "05a0-d4fb-d461-9697",name: "newfolder",type: "directory",path: "model/newfolder",children: [{id: "e8e5-f0c8-6664-96e1",name: "newname",type: "file",path: "model/newfolder/newname"}]}]
  
console.log(Array.from(find(data, t => /newn/.test(t))))        
console.log(Array.from(find(data, matchProperty(/newn/))))
console.log(Array.from(find(data, hasFileType("yaml"))))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

**refinements**

Currently `find` casts all `path` segments to strings. Per Scott's comment, we might wish to maintain *numeric* values of array indices. This can be done by treating arrays as different from objects. This definition also uses generator delegation, `yield *`, to simplify nested `for` loops -

```js
function* find (t, query, path = [])
{ if (query(t)) yield {path, value: t}
  switch (t?.constructor)
  { case Array:
      for (const [k, v] of t.entries())
        yield *find(v, query, [...path, k])
      break
    case Object:
      for (const [k, v] of Object.entries(t))
        yield *find(v, query, [...path, k])
      break
  }
}
```

```js
Array.from(find(data, t => /newn/.test(t)))
```

| path | value |
| --- | --- |
| [3, "children", 0, "name"] | "newname" |
| [3, "children", 0, "path"] | "model/newfolder/newname" |

```js
data[3]["children"][0]["name"]  // => "newname"
data[3]["children"][0]["path"]  // => "model/newfolder/newname"
```

**iter**

You might dislike introducing `find1` but I only did that to simplify the original answer. In reality this is a generic function to work on any iterable. I typically have an `iter` module which contains the functions for working with iterables, such as the result of a generator like `find` -

```js
// iter.js

const iter = t =>
  t?.[Symbol.iterator]()

function first (t)
{ for (const v of t)
    return v
}

function toArray (t)
{ const r = []
  for (const v of t)
    r.push(v)
  return r
}

export { iter, first, toArray }
```

Having a separate module gives you a **barrier of abstraction** where you are free to make changes as you see fit. It makes it easier to test things and keeps us from repeating this functionality every time we need it somewhere else in our program. We can import `iter` wherever it is needed -

```js
// main.js

import { toArray, first } from "./iter.js"

const data = ...

function* find (...) { ... }
```

```js
toArray(find(data, t => /newn/.test(t)))
```

| path | value |
| --- | --- |
| [3, "children", 0, "name"] | "newname" |
| [3, "children", 0, "path"] | "model/newfolder/newname" |

```js
first(find(data, t => /newn/.test(t)))
```

| path | value |
| --- | --- |
| [3, "children", 0, "name"] | "newname" |

If you prefer to work in a more object-oriented way, we can write a simple class `Iterator` that wraps our plain functions -

```js
// iter.js (continued)

// ...

class Iterator
{ constructor(t) { this.t = iter(t) }
  first() { return first(this.t) }
  toArray() { return toArray(this.t) }
}

export default Iterator
```

You now have a dual-purpose module that can be used in functional style *or* object-oriented style -

```js
// main.js

import Iterator from "./iter.js"

const data = ...

function* find (...) { ... }
```

```js
new Iterator(find(data, t => /newn/.test(t))).toArray()
```

| path | value |
| --- | --- |
| [3, "children", 0, "name"] | "newname" |
| [3, "children", 0, "path"] | "model/newfolder/newname" |

```js
new Iterator(find(data, t => /newn/.test(t))).first()
```

| path | value |
| --- | --- |
| [3, "children", 0, "name"] | "newname" |

Comment: I like this a great deal.  We've both been developing answers like this here.  I prefer for my array indices in the paths to be numbers.  It doesn't matter for searching, but it allows us to use such paths to regenerate a complete or partial clone of the original in an unambiguous manner.

Comment: I might also rename `find` to `filter` and `find1` to `find` for consistency with JS array methods.   Or I might rename it in some other way and use it to derive an array-returning `filter` and a scalar-or-undefined-returning `find`.

Comment: Scott I hemmed and hawed over trading simplicity for numeric indices. For whatever reason, I do prefer numeric indices are preserved, when possible. I made an update to address this comment and help others see what we're talking about.

Comment: `find1` is also a result of over-simplifying things. In reality, `find1` is a generic for any iterable. it's common for me to to do this instead of introducing another dependency. for the benefit of people that may wish to dive deeper, i added (a sample) of my `iter` module ^_^'

Answer (score 2):

**Update**: the various versions of `flatFilter` have been updated with a suggestion from user [@Thankyou](https://stackoverflow.com/users/633183).

I would probably start with a generic function to do a deep filtering into a flat list, one that works with an arbitrary predicate, something like this:

```js
const flatFilter = (pred) => (xs = []) =>
  xs .flatMap (x => (pred (x) ? [x] : []) .concat (flatFilter (pred) (x.children)))
```

Then we could use it to build your search function on the `path` nodes:

```js
const searchPath = (target) => 
  flatFilter (({path = ''}) => path .includes (target))
```

and we would call it like this:

```js
searchPath ('newn') (input)
```

So overall, it might look like this:

```js
const flatFilter = (pred) => (xs = []) =>
  xs .flatMap (x => (pred (x) ? [x] : []) .concat (flatFilter (pred) (x.children)))

const searchPath = (target) => 
  flatFilter (({path = ''}) => path .includes (target))

const input = [{id: "95c3-1e74-48c7-ec7e", name: "model.yaml", type: "file", path: "model/model.yaml"}, {id: "115c-d112-5ce5-a7e8", name: "storage-complextypes.yaml", type: "file", path: "model/storage-complextypes.yaml"}, {id: "9f51-93b5-4160-0237", name: "storage-simpletypes.yaml", type: "file", path: "model/storage-simpletypes.yaml"}, {id: "05a0-d4fb-d461-9697", name: "newfolder", type: "directory", path: "model/newfolder", children: [{id: "e8e5-f0c8-6664-96e1", name: "newname", type: "file", path: "model/newfolder/newname"}]}]

console .log ('newn:', searchPath ('newn') (input))
console .log ('type:', searchPath ('type') (input))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

If you preferred your main function to be called like `searchPath (input, 'newn')`, it would be a minor change, still using the same base function:

```js
const searchPath = (xs, target) => 
  flatFilter ('children') (({path = ''}) => path .includes (target)) (xs)
```

And if we wanted to make this more generic, so that the name of the descendent node (here `'children'` is configurable, it's just one more parameter:

```js
const flatFilter = (prop) => (pred) => (xs = []) =>
  xs.flatMap (x => (pred (x) ? [x] : []).concat (flatFilter (prop) (pred) (x.children)))
```

And our main function would now look like this:

```js
const searchPath = (xs, target) => 
  flatFilter ('children') (({path = ''}) => path .includes (target)) (xs)
```

Finally, the above does a depth-first traversal.  If we wanted a breadth-first traversal, it's only slightly more complex.  Here's one version:

```js
const flatFilter = (pred) => (xs = []) => 
  xs .length == 0 
    ? [] 
    : xs .flatMap (x => pred (x) ? [x] : [])
         .concat (flatFilter (pred) (xs .flatMap (({children = []}) => children)))
```

And here's one that abstracts `'children'`:

```js
const flatFilter = (prop) => (pred) => (xs = []) => 
  xs .length == 0 
    ? [] 
    : xs .flatMap (x => pred (x) ? [x] : [])
         .concat (flatFilter (prop) (pred) (xs .flatMap (({[prop]: c = []}) => c)))
```

I think quite often, reaching for a *more* generic version of what we're trying to do actually ends up simplifying an approach.  Here, by separating the predicate we apply from the tree traversal, we can both simplify our custom function and have available a reusable function for other parts of our app or other apps.

Comment: beautiful functional expressions and supporting explanations. would you allow me to nitpick the `...])])`? We could change the input parameter from `xs` to `xs = []` and write `x => (pred (x) ? [x] : []) .concat (flatFilter (pred) (x.children))` and untangle the "laminated" braces. just an idea :D

Comment: @Thankyou: Yes, you're right.  That's cleaner.  Updated.  I often like the spread syntax in such situations, and I do wish it didn't need some of those wrappers to use in arrays.  But `concat` is definitely an improvement in this situation.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways in achieving the expected output. Here I'm using `Array.reduce`.

```js
const data = [{id:"95c3-1e74-48c7-ec7e",name:"model.yaml",type:"file",path:"model/model.yaml",},{id:"115c-d112-5ce5-a7e8",name:"storage-complextypes.yaml",type:"file",path:"model/storage-complextypes.yaml",},{id:"9f51-93b5-4160-0237",name:"storage-simpletypes.yaml",type:"file",path:"model/storage-simpletypes.yaml",},{id:"05a0-d4fb-d461-9697",name:"newfolder",type:"directory",path:"model/newfolder",children:[{id:"e8e5-f0c8-6664-96e1",name:"newname",type:"file",path:"model/newfolder/newname",}]}];

const getFilteredData = (data, name) => {
  const addIfMatching = (res, obj, name) => {
    if (obj.name.includes(name)) {
      res.push(obj);
    }
  }

  return data.reduce((res, obj) => {
    const { children, ...rest } = obj;
    addIfMatching(res, rest, name);
    if (children) {
      children.forEach(child => {
        addIfMatching(res, child, name)
      })
    }
    return res;
  }, [])
}

console.log("names having `newn`");
console.log(getFilteredData(data, "newn"));

console.log("-------------")
console.log("names having `new`");
console.log(getFilteredData(data, "new"));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Note: I have considered only one sub level of the parent object. i.e., only one level of `children` in the top level object.

Comment: Thank you so much, but i need the function which will be working any type of nesting

Comment: You mean any levels of nesting?

Comment: yeah, thats what i mean

Answer (score 1):

Here is an iterative solution using [object-scan](https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan). Adds a dependency, but you might find it more legible and maintainable. E.g. searching within multiple fields would be very easy.

```js
// const objectScan = require('object-scan');

const myData = [{ id: '95c3-1e74-48c7-ec7e', name: 'model.yaml', type: 'file', path: 'model/model.yaml' }, { id: '115c-d112-5ce5-a7e8', name: 'storage-complextypes.yaml', type: 'file', path: 'model/storage-complextypes.yaml' }, { id: '9f51-93b5-4160-0237', name: 'storage-simpletypes.yaml', type: 'file', path: 'model/storage-simpletypes.yaml' }, { id: '05a0-d4fb-d461-9697', name: 'newfolder', type: 'directory', path: 'model/newfolder', children: [{ id: 'e8e5-f0c8-6664-96e1', name: 'newname', type: 'file', path: 'model/newfolder/newname' }] }];

const find = objectScan(['**(^children$).name'], {
  useArraySelector: false,
  rtn: 'parent',
  filterFn: ({ value, context }) => value.includes(context)
});

console.log(find(myData, 'newn'));
/* => [ {
  id: 'e8e5-f0c8-6664-96e1',
  name: 'newname',
  type: 'file',
  path: 'model/newfolder/newname'
} ] */
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/object-scan@14.3.0"></script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)