# Javascript Find In Nested Object

Tags: javascript, object, nested

Probably a simple question but I can't figure it out. I have an nested object in javascript like this and i have function for find object in object.

```
[
  {
    "id": "general",
    "components": [
      {
        "id": "na17ea10-e126",
        "parentId": "general",
        "type": "L6",
        "components": [
          {
            "id": "n5c4fd4a-5fe0",
            "parentId": "na17ea10-e126",
            "type": "L6E",
            "components": [
              {
                "id": "n0f17d51-143e",
                "parentId": "n5c4fd4a-5fe0",
                "type": "Text",
                "components": []
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "id": "n7e86ff5-cfd2",
            "parentId": "na17ea10-e126",
            "type": "L6E",
            "components": []
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

and I have a search function

```
  findInSchema(o, id){
    let i;
    for (i of o) {
      if(i.id==id){
        return i;
      }else if(i.components.length>0){
        return findInSchema(i.components,id);
      }
      
    }
  }
```

as in the above object example;

```
findInSchema(obj, 'n5c4fd4a-5fe0')
```

give me

```
{
            "id": "n5c4fd4a-5fe0",
            "parentId": "na17ea10-e126",
            "type": "L6E",
            "components": [
              {
                "id": "n0f17d51-143e",
                "parentId": "n5c4fd4a-5fe0",
                "type": "Text",
                "components": []
              }
            ]
          }
```

but in the other example on the same layer

```
findInSchema(obj, 'n7e86ff5-cfd2')
```

give me 'undefined'

Comment: You are basically always terminating the loop when an object has "children", no matter whether an object was found or not. In order words you are always only looking at the *first* object in the `components` arrays and never consider the remaining ones.

Comment: many excellent ideas here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67399929/creating-deep-filter-by-input-value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want to terminate the recursive search just because an object **has** `components` -- you only want to terminate it if you find what you're looking for within those components.

```js
function findInSchema(o, id) {
  let i;
  for (i of o) {
    if(i.id==id){
      return i;
    } else if(i.components.length>0){
      const inComponents = findInSchema(i.components,id);
      if (typeof(inComponents) != "undefined") return inComponents;
    }
  }
}

const obj = [
  {
    "id": "general",
    "components": [
      {
        "id": "na17ea10-e126",
        "parentId": "general",
        "type": "L6",
        "components": [
          {
            "id": "n5c4fd4a-5fe0",
            "parentId": "na17ea10-e126",
            "type": "L6E",
            "components": [
              {
                "id": "n0f17d51-143e",
                "parentId": "n5c4fd4a-5fe0",
                "type": "Text",
                "components": []
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "id": "n7e86ff5-cfd2",
            "parentId": "na17ea10-e126",
            "type": "L6E",
            "components": []
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]

console.log(findInSchema(obj, 'n5c4fd4a-5fe0'));
console.log(findInSchema(obj, 'n7e86ff5-cfd2'));
```